# Custom list class slicing functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to implement my own type of list called `Stack`.  I also want to add slicing functionality with the `__getitem__` method like so:

```
class Stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def __getitem__(self, slc):
        return self.items[slc]

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
```

Now if I create a `Stack` instance and append some elements to it I get the `Stack` type:

```
st = Stack()
st.append('hi')
st.append('bye')
st.append('hello')
print(type(st)) # Stack type
```

but if I slice my Stack, it becomes a list again:

```
st_sliced = st[1:2]
print(type(st_sliced)) # List type
```

how can I make st_sliced to stay `Stack` type after slicing?

Comment: What you are calling a stack is a far cry from what virtually anyone reading your code will recognize as a stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return self.items[slc]` return a list - this is why the type is not a Stack anymore.

The code below keep the type as Stack.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        if items is None:
            items = []
        self.items = items

    def __getitem__(self, slc):
        return Stack(self.items[slc])

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)


st = Stack()
st.append('hi')
st.append('bye')
st.append('hello')
print(type(st))
st_sliced = st[1:2]
print(type(st_sliced))
```

Comment: See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#what-you-wrote for understanding the `__init__` implementation.